# deleting lines after a specific string is greater than a value (bash or python)

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed

I have a data file with a list of numbers like that:

```
5 5
6 6
4 4
3 3
4 4
3 3
2 2
```

I wish to pick out the first row that has the two columns with numbers <=3 and delete all the rows after that. Hence my result file will just be:

```
5 5 
6 6
4 4 
3 3
```

Does anyone know how to use awk/sed for this?

Comment: What have __you__ tried?

Comment: choose your weapon, try something, else it's just too broad. See [ask]

Comment: so I played around with awk and used awk '($1 <= 3 ) && ($2 <= 3 ) ' filename and that just picked out 3 3, 3 3, 2 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an awk solution:

```
$ awk '1; $1<=3&&$2<=3{exit}' file
5 5
6 6
4 4
3 3
```

Explained:

```
awk '
1;                           # output record
$1 <= 3 && $2 <= 3 { exit }  # if it was as requested, exit
' file
```

Comment: This is great and it works seamlessly! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following ***sed*** approach:

```
sed -n '1,/[0-3] [0-3]/p' file
```

The output:

```
5 5    
6 6    
4 4    
3 3
```

---

`1,/[0-3] [0-3]` - address range starting from the first line and captures lines till encountering 2 digits which are less or equal to `3`(inclusively).

> An address range is specified with two addresses separated by a comma
>   (,). Addresses can be numeric, regular expressions, or a mix of both.

Answer (score 0):

For Python, print every line and just break out of the loop when your criteria is met:

```
>>> while open('somefile.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line, end='')
            p, q = map(int, line.split())
            if p <= 3 or q <= 3:
                break


5 5
6 6
4 4
3 3
```

Here is an AWK solution:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {flag=0} flag==0 {print ; flag=$1<=3 && $1<=3}' somefile.txt
5 5
6 6
4 4
3 3
```

Comment: Do you mind telling me in detail how that works? I just picked up python and I'm still terrible at it..

Comment: I put in a more straight-forward variant.  The *takewhile* approach is harder to get right.

Comment: Nice! This is something useful that i've been looking for. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Raymond I've made an edit that was I think just a typo - but a change to your print statement such that it reproduces the results you have included in your codeblock - feel free to revert if you want.